# Counting number of arrangements with conditions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm working on the following question.

(a) How many six digit numbers can be formed with the digits 1, 2, . . . , 6 without repetition?

(b) How many of these begin with 2?

(c) In how many of the numbers in (a) do odd and even digits appear alternately?

(d) In how many of the numbers in (a) are the digits 1 and 2 separated?

My answers are:

a) 6!

b) 5!

c) 2 x 3! x 3!

d) 6! - 2 x 5!

I would appreciate it if anyone could look over these just to check if they agree :)

Comment: All of your answers are correct.  However, it would help users of this site if you would explain your reasoning, which would make it easier to detect any errors you may have made.

Comment: Well done! It is correct! But I agree with @N.F.Taussig, you should explain your reasoning so we could understand if you are thinking right or not!

Comment: Many thanks :) my thinking for part c) was there are 3! ways of ordering the odd numbers, 3! ways of ordering the even numbers, and two ways of “interleaving” them: oeoeoe and eoeoeo (where e means even number in this position and o means odd number in this position)

Comment: And for part d): count the number where 1 and 2 do touch and take away from total. To do this, treat 1 and 2 as one symbol to get 5! arrangements, and multiply by 2 because for every place where the 1 and 2 symbol was we can either have 12 or 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers and logic shared in the comments are all exactly right.  Keep up the good work.